# How to complete this alternative proof for the FTFGAG

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, alternative-proof, finitely-generated

I'm trying to prove the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. But I cannot an argument involving free abelian group; that is, **avoid** using the following proposition:

> **(Don't-Use-This-) Proposition.** Let $F$ be a free abelian group and $G$ its subgroup. Then there is a basis $x_1 ,\, \cdots,\, x_n$ of $F$, a positive integer $r$, and positive integers $d_1,\, \cdots,\, d_r$ such that $d_1 | d_2 | \cdots | d_r$ and $\{d_i x_i \}$ is a basis of $G$.

Avoid the above. This is the request of the exercise 2 in section II-2, *Algebra* by Hungerford, I guess.

The exercise asks first to prove and use the following observation, *which I've already done.*

> **Obsevation.** Let $G$ be a **finite** abelian group (not 'finitely generated') and $x$ be an element of maximal order. Then the cyclic subgroup $\langle x \rangle$ of $G$ is a direct summand of $G$.

So the last thing I have to do is completing the proof of the FTFGAG with the above observation. But to do that, I have to decompose a finitely generated abelian group $G$ into two pieces: torsion part and torsion-free part, because the observation works only for finite groups. So my question is:

1. Without any aid of the above Don't-Use-This-Proposition, how to decompose a fin. gen. abelian group into the torsion and torsion-free part?
2. Or, is it the must? Must I rely on the D-U-T-P?

Comment: It seems to invite an induction on the number of generators.  The cited observation lets you peel off one generator (of maximal order) and treat the direct summand apart from that cyclic subgroup.  Some work is needed to show that in doing this the number of generators drops by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you know how to prove that a torsion-free FGAG is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}^n$ for some $n$?

The torsion subgroup $T(G)$ of a FGAG is finite, so you can apply the result you have proved to show that $T(G)$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Then $G/T(G)$ is torsion-free, and you can find a complement $C \cong {\mathbb Z}^n$ of $T(G)$ in  $G$ and then $G = T(G) \oplus C$, and you are done.